# Is the "switch user" dropdown in Azure, Office, and other products available for integration to AAD/B2C web apps?

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, blazor, webassembly, microsoft-identity-platform

I am interested in including the dropdown-account-selection feature that's available in Azure and Office in my personal ASP.NET (core/Blazor WebAssembly) app.

This often occurs when more than one AAD account is being used, or when more than one directory is being accessed at a time.

[image]

Ideally I would have a more compact view (like Google) and one that switches as quickly too

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible .Please raise [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/) or vote for similar voice